# Starting a no launcher activity from another package

Tags: android, securityexception, start-activity

I try to start an activity from another package, but it has not LAUNCHER category

```
Intent i = new Intent();            
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(maxVerPackageName, maxVerClassName));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
startActivity(i);
```

I faced the Exception: "An exception occurred: java.lang.SecurityException"

what's wrong, please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other activity is enforcing a permission. So that only apps that have the permission or same uid can launch the activity.

Edit: If you have written other app

then add this attribute to the other activity which you are trying to launch

```
android:exported="true"
```

Comment: The other activity is also written by me. How can I share one uid between two applications?

Comment: did you  check by using exported = true?